# TextView customSelectionActionModeCallback issues in NestScrollView nested RecyclerView

Tags: android, textview

I have a `NestedScrollView` contain a `RecyclerView`, each adapter item have

1. TextView one
2. ImageView
3. TextView two

and I want to custom TextView select action use kt ext

```
fun TextView.customMenuCallBack() {
    var selectAll = false
    customSelectionActionModeCallback = object : ActionMode.Callback {
        override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
            item?.let {
                return when (it.itemId) {
                    android.R.id.selectAll -> {
                        selectAll = true
                        false
                    }

                    android.R.id.copy -> {
                        if (selectAll) {
                            //TODO set content
                            try {
                                val clipboard: ClipboardManager = context.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
                                val clip = ClipData.newPlainText(context.toString(), content)
                                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip)
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                e.printStackTrace()
                            }
                        }
                      
                        //make custom action work return true
                        true
                    }
                    else -> {
                        false
                    }
                }
            }
            return false
        }

        override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {

        }

    }
}
```

I appear some issues：

1. menu not hide after click menu item
2. Affects scrolling, when scrolling forward it suddenly back to nearby selected text position
3. Not workinig in MIUI ROM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed part of issues

1. menu not hide after click menu item
2. Affects scrolling, when scrolling forward it suddenly back to nearby selected text position

```
fun TextView.customMenuCallBack() {
    var selectAll = false
    customSelectionActionModeCallback = object : ActionMode.Callback {
        override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
            item?.let {
                return when (it.itemId) {
                    android.R.id.selectAll -> {
                        selectAll = true
                        false
                    }

                    android.R.id.copy -> {
                        if (selectAll) {
                            //TODO set content
                            try {
                                val clipboard: ClipboardManager = context.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
                                val clip = ClipData.newPlainText(context.toString(), content)
                                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip)
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                e.printStackTrace()
                            }
                        }
                        //fixed first issue
                        mode?.finish()
                        //fixed second issue
                        clearFocus()
                        //make custom action work return true
                        true
                    }
                    else -> {
                        false
                    }
                }
            }
            return false
        }

        override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {

        }

    }
}
```

update： Custom my NestedScrollView2:NestedScrollView and override

```
  override fun requestChildFocus(child: View?, focused: View?) {
     //do nothing prevent focused issued
  }
```